# Force warnings about crossing branches when running Update using TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

When getting the latest code from a Mercurial repo on the command line, if there are changesets that need to be merged Mercurial raises a warning:

```
hg up
abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --check to force update)
```

This is what I expect, and from the Mercurial book it says "Mercurial is telling us that the hg update command won't do a merge; it won't update the working directory when it thinks we might want to do a merge, unless we force it to do so."  At this point I know I need to merge.

How can I get the same behaviour using TortoiseHg?  When I hit "Update", it happily updates me to the most recent changeset.  Is there a way to warn me that a merge is probably needed?  The "Always merge (when possible)" option seems to only apply when you have uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get an error from `hg update` on the command-line is that it doesn't know which revision to pick.  There are 2 divergent default heads.

If you were to execute `hg update -r <specific rev>`, the command completes without error.

When using TortoiseHg, you update by:

1. right-clicking a specific changeset
2. selecting `Update...`

This translates to `hg update -r <rev>`, so there is no error.

Using TortoiseHg, you always have the revision graph in front of you.  The graph shows when newly pulled changesets create a new head.

Answer (score 1):

The Mercurial abort you are seeing is occurring because you have outstanding (ie: non-committed) changes in your working directory, are trying to perform an update, and Mercurial has decided that you should probably perform a merge instead.

TortoiseHg should also warn you about this, but it will do so in a different way. It will spawn a dialogue that asks if you want to **Discard**, **Merge**, or **Shelve** your outstanding changes. This is what it looks like in TortoiseHg v2.X.X, but it should be similar in v1.1.X:

[image]

If you're not seeing this in TortoiseHg, you may not have any outstanding changes. Try it again - are you seeing these options?

Comment: In this case I have no uncommitted changes though.  There are two changesets with a single parent.  The process I'm trying follows the process exactly at [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html#id353830).  I've linked the section where the abort message is expected.

Comment: @Nick I see what you're saying, in this case Mercurial is identifying a pattern that it thinks should be a merge. I will have to investigate if TortoiseHg supports this...