# HG Merge: Outstanding uncommited changes

Tags: merge, mercurial

I have a file, version.txt and other files. I changed the other files, but didn't touch version.txt.

So, I've tried to push a commit, and saw a Remote heads error. (There is a changeset which modifies `versions.txt` file)

I did a `hg pull`, then `hg update`.

The error is: `abort: crosses branches (merge branches or use --clean to discard changes)`

Then I tried `hg merge`: `abort: outstanding uncommitted changes (use 'hg status' to list changes)`

But I don't undertand, why if the versions.txt isn't modified by me, why can't it just merge.

This is something I will be doing a lot, which is, develop and merge, to keep inline with the main dev repo. How can I fix this thing?

HG Status:

```
M printbox/web/printbox/controllers/ct_adm_colas.php
M printbox/web/printbox/controllers/ct_adm_jobs.php
M printbox/web/printbox/controllers/ct_form_configurar_cola.php
M printbox/web/printbox/core/MY_Controller.php
M printbox/web/printbox/css/estilos.css
M printbox/web/printbox/js/js_tablas_colas-jobs_ajax.js
M printbox/web/printbox/models/md_cola.php
M printbox/web/printbox/models/md_job.php
M printbox/web/printbox/views/vw_tabla_colas.php
M printbox/web/printbox/views/vw_tabla_jobs.php
A printbox/web/printbox/core/MY_Model.php
? .idea/.name
? .idea/encodings.xml
? .idea/misc.xml
? .idea/modules.xml
? .idea/printboxweb.iml
? .idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
? .idea/vcs.xml
? .idea/workspace.xml
```

EIDT: Before and After following the suggested fix, the graph log looks like this:

```
o  changeset:   19:e21fa7b131b0
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      17:54f59f253460
|  user:        JCV
|  date:        Tue Apr 22 12:33:36 2014 -0300
|  summary:     # Modificar nombre de producto para version
|
| @  changeset:   18:a03eaad764cd
|/   user:        Jorge S <js@fusiondev.com.ar>
|    date:        Wed Apr 23 16:28:01 2014 -0300
|    summary:     Eliminar método que no se utiliza.
|
o  changeset:   17:54f59f253460
|  user:        Jorge S <js@fusiondev.com.ar>
|  date:        Mon Apr 21 17:25:23 2014 -0300
|  summary:     Incluir SWHelper en Printbox.php
|


@    changeset:   21:1698791a9310
|\   tag:         tip
| |  parent:      20:3bfa1251da1b
| |  parent:      19:e21fa7b131b0
| |  user:        Jorge S <js@fusiondev.c
| |  date:        Thu Apr 24 13:59:25 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     Merge
| |
| o  changeset:   20:3bfa1251da1b
| |  parent:      18:a03eaad764cd
| |  user:        Jorge S <js@fusiondev.c
| |  date:        Thu Apr 24 13:57:23 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     Commit de archivos
| |
o |  changeset:   19:e21fa7b131b0
| |  parent:      17:54f59f253460
| |  user:        JCV
| |  date:        Tue Apr 22 12:33:36 2014 -0300
| |  summary:     # Modificar nombre de producto 
| |
| o  changeset:   18:a03eaad764cd
|/   user:        Jorge S <js@fusiondev.c
|    date:        Wed Apr 23 16:28:01 2014 -0300
|    summary:     Eliminar método que no se utili
|
o  changeset:   17:54f59f253460
|  user:        Jorge S <js@fusiondev.com
|  date:        Mon Apr 21 17:25:23 2014 -0300
|  summary:     Incluir SWHelper en Printbox.php
```

Comment: Do a `hg status`, are any files listed, except possibly files with a question mark ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen there I updated

Comment: You have uncommitted changes locally, that's why Mercurial complains. If you decide to update to a different changeset, Mercurial will try to "merge" your local uncommitted changes with whatever has been done between your working folder parent and the changeset you want to update to. Merging can not be done with uncommitted changes, since the act of merging will modify files leaving them uncommitted. So... are those files supposed to be committed? If so, then you should do so, then you can update and/or merge.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is right. You can also shelf your local changes, to bring them back later, if you have the extension enabled.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But I dont understand why I have to merge. It is not a branch, it is the main line. Is it too much to ask for a dumb-proof explanation?. I thought the UPDATE would bring the files modified in the HEAD changeset. If it has no problem, then my local repo (Where I've been working) would be updated with latest server version. It must be noted that in this case, I did not modify a file that comes in the remote changeset

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982368/force-warnings-about-crossing-branches-when-running-update-using-tortoisehg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, forget about `version.txt`, it is not relevant here. You have 2 repos, one on your system, and the remote one.

When you tried to push the first time, you tried to send a changeset on the remote repo, and you got an error saying that you cannot push a second head, unless you issue a `--force` option. This is because someone else already beat you to it and pushed a changeset (modifying `version.txt`) on the same branch (what you call *main line*, is actually a branch too, and it is probably called **default**).

What you did next is good, you pulled the changes from the remote repo to solve the 2 heads problem. By doing so, you are the one ending up with 2 heads on the default. This is fine, it is easy to solve, we'll get to it soon.

Your current state must look like this

```
% hg log --graph
o  changeset:   14:3cfac6413110
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      10:d573f47ecc2d
|  summary:     vb
|
| @  changeset:   13:d8edfdb0532e
|/   parent:      10:d573f47ecc2d
|    summary:     commit to subr2
|
```

Now it gets complicated when you do the `hg update` because mercurial notices that something is wrong with your repo. You will need to fix the 2 heads issue by doing a merge, just like mercurial's suggestion.

However, doing `hg merge` gives you a second error, this time because you have not committed all your changes in your repo. Now you have 2 choices. You see those files with the `M` in front of them when you tried the `hg status` command? If you indeed modified them, and you want to include them in the repo, do the following:

```
hg commit -m "Committing remaining files"
hg merge
hg commit -m "Merge"
```

This is to commit the left-over changes, merge the 2 heads, then commit the merge changeset. The reason why mercurial does not want to update with uncommitted changes is for security reasons. It does not want you to loose you current work. And this brings me to the second option. If, however, the changes in the modified files are not wanted, you can discard those changes. It is possible you attempted something else during the confusion, which updated some files and left you in an *in-between* state. If that is the case, you can quickly discard the changes and solve the problem by doing these commands instead (loosing your changes):

```
hg update --clean
hg merge
hg commit -m "Merge"
```

The update will simply clean out the repo, and a merge will be possible. Once the merge committed, then you can issue the final push.

```
hg push
```

If you're lucky and no one pushed anything else on the remote repo, the push should succeed. Otherwise, you can pull, merge, commit and push again.

Comment: I tried following your advice, I ended having an unwanted "branch" that I had to merge, thus showed that way in logs. It's not very clear for me why it must be that way, if I clone the repo again, I have the latest version. If then I copy my modified files, I do not have to do a merge, just commit the changes. I didn't want to commit my changes before, because it was still under development (just wanted to push a small bugfix from another thing). I must find a way to securely develop new features while still being able to update to the repo last state

Comment: @Jorge Features should be developed in their own named branch, at least this is what I strongly suggest. When your feature is complete, then you merge back in default. http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-named-branches